# How to make bootstrap li active class have full height in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
/* Navigation Setup */
.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navigation{
 background-color: #203260;
}
#navigation .navbar-default {
 background-color: #203260;
}
#navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
#navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{
    background-color: #065690;
}
#navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 margin-top: 15px;
}
#navigation .nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right {
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>          
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>      
          </ul>          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Call Us Today! <br> (123) 456-789</a></li>            
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Please See the Output in full screen. **I want the class which is active should have full height.**
 Example Home is active class so I should only see light blue color on top and bottom. But I see only light blue color around it and dark blue color on top and bottom of text.

Something Like
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) rule on your `a` tag to solve this.

```
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
#navigation {
  background-color: #203260;
}
#navigation .navbar {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #203260;
}
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: #065690;
}
#navigation .navbar .navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #navigation .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  #navigation .navbar .navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
  #navigation .navbar .navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a > div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Information</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Call Us Today! @ <div>(123) 456-789</div></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```